# Spring - POST with binary file - Character decoding failed

Tags: spring, post, decoding, bin

I'm running a spring-boot app that seems to be having trouble with a particular request. The request is a POST containing binary data however, when the JavaServlet(Or tomcat?) receives it, it doesn't know how to decode it so it produces the following error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Character decoding failed. Parameter [0  *H÷
          0 UUS1#0!U
S§¥ø§'ôZúöf¿(å_Ý«"õéñ¤åyl¢Ýg0izt¡÷~ÅüvDt¿Äû¨Ë åt@òÔÊdJRBq%2¶ úFsX] with value [] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
```

I'm aware of the following config which seems to have some effect on it, but I don't know what to set the value to for a post that contains a binary:

```
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8 #I've also tried UTF-16
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT (ANSWER):
You can fix this using an apache proxy with the following configuration:

```
<Location /endpoint/>
    ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:443/endpoint/
    RequestHeader unset Content-Type
    RequestHeader set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
</Location>
```

Unsetting the Content-Type is optional, the set should override I believe. However, I'm not 100% the field is case-insensitive. It's possible `RequestHeader unset content-type` should be added as well.

Comment: What is the value of the request's Content-Type header?

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`application/x-www-form-urleconded` isn't an appropriate content type for binary data. Tomcat thinks you've POSTed a form to it and is trying to parse the names and values of the fields from the binary data. You should use a content type that's appropriate for binary data. `application/octet-stream` is one option.

Comment: I unfortunately have no control over the request being made. It comes as pre-packaged code from Adobe. Is there a way I could have Spring interpret this request as an octet-stream when it receives it?

Comment: You might be able to use a filter that wraps the request and changes the content type, but I can't say for sure based on the information you've provided. Perhaps you can update the question with some more details of exactly when in the handling of the request the error occurs? A stacktrace, if there is one, would be useful.

Comment: I tried doing a filter (wrapper) and I tried doing a servlet but unfortunately it doesn't catch the error in time. I had to build a second proxy in front of it (in python) to solve the problem. Your answer is correct as this was the issue, so I'm going to mark it as the answer and put my python implementation as an edit for others if they have to deal with this Adobe Access player issue.

Comment: FYI, no need for a python implementation. I was able to get an Apache proxy to do this for me easily.